# dial codes with phone number in magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery

How can I put an option to choose country dial codes with the phone number in magneto 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code

Create requirejs-config.js and add below code

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "intlTelInput": 'Namespace_Module/js/intlTelInput',
        "intlTelInputUtils": 'Namespace_Module/js/utils',
        "internationalTelephoneInput": 'NameSpace_Module/js/internationalTelephoneInput'
    },

    shim: {
        'intlTelInput': {
            'deps':['jquery', 'knockout']
        },
        'internationalTelephoneInput': {
            'deps':['jquery', 'intlTelInput']
        }
    }
};
```

download js from https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/

in layout file add css

```
<css src="Ffc_Base::css/intlTelInput.css"/>
```

add below code phtml file where you want to display

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'intlTelInput'
    ], function ($) {
        $("input[name='telephone']").intlTelInput(<?php echo $viewModel->phoneConfig(); ?>)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: does not work with 2.4.3 :'(